# Change SQL Query to LINQ, asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

How to change this SQL query to LINQ? I've tried it several times, but it didn't work

```
SELECT Payment.ID, Payment.TotalGroupID, PaymentTrans.PaymentID, PaymentTrans.TotalGroupID as TotalGroupID1, PaymentTrans.TransferStatus
FROM PaymentTrans INNER JOIN Payment
ON (PaymentTrans.PaymentID = Payment.ID OR PaymentTrans.TotalGroupID = payment.TotalGroupID)
WHERE (PaymentTrans.TransferStatusis NULL  OR (PaymentTrans.TransferStatus <> '01' and PaymentTrans.TransferStatus <> '02'))
```

and this is my try

```
var a= (from x in db.PaymentTransactions
        join p in db.Payments
        on
        x.PaymentID equals p.ID
        where x.TransferStatus== null || (x.TransferStatus!= "01" && x.TransferStatus!= "02")
                            select new { x, p }).ToList();
```

but it still wrong LINQ, because in my query I have 2 conditions in ON Clause. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers above filter on both conditions, they should filter one of the conditions according to the question (PaymentID or TotalPaymentID). You can either write two seperate queries and use a union or use a Cartesian product before filtering.

```
var result = (from paymentTransaction in db.PaymentTransactions
                      join payment in db.Payments on paymentTransaction.PaymentID equals payment.ID
                      where paymentTransaction.TransferStatus == null || (paymentTransaction.TransferStatus != "01" && paymentTransaction.TransferStatus != "02")
                      select new { paymentTransaction, payment }).Union
                     (from paymentTransaction in db.PaymentTransactions
                      join payment in db.Payments on paymentTransaction.TotalGroupID equals payment.TotalGroupID
                      where paymentTransaction.TransferStatus == null || (paymentTransaction.TransferStatus != "01" && paymentTransaction.TransferStatus != "02")
                      select new { paymentTransaction, payment });

        var cartResult = from paymentTransaction in db.PaymentTransactions
                         from payment in db.Payments
                         where paymentTransaction.PaymentID == payment.ID || paymentTransaction.TotalGroupID == payment.TotalGroupID
                         where paymentTransaction.TransferStatus == null || (paymentTransaction.TransferStatus != "01" && paymentTransaction.TransferStatus != "02")
                         select new { paymentTransaction, payment };
```

Comment: I get an error at `select new (paymentTransaction, payment)`. 
the error is `(range valiable)? payment Transaction`

Comment: Updated the queries, I made some typos, code now compiles.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
var query = (from x in db.PaymentTransactions
             join p in db.Payments 
             on x.PaymentID equals p.ID //main condition of join
             where  ((x.TransferStatus == null || 
             (x.TransferStatus != "01" && x.TransferStatus!= "02")) //your `where` condition
             || x.TotalGroupID == p.TotalGroupID) //your second or join
             select new {x,p})
            .ToList();
```

Comment: It's not working, if I execute a SQL query I get 13 data, but if I debug the LINQ  that you provide only get 10 data. in SQL Query, they should filter one of the conditions (PaymentID or Total Payment).

Comment: hi, I cant use `select new { x, p }) .ToList();` because there is a red line in the code

Comment: @chaeusangchen can you hover and what is the message?

Comment: @chaeusangchen hope it has helped you :D

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add multiple ON in LINQ. the solution of your problem above can be solved like this.

**Hint**: just use multiple Where.

```
var result = 
(
    from trans in db.PaymentTransactions
    join payment in db.payments
    on trans.PaymentID equals payment.ID
    where trans.TotalGroupID == payment.TotalGroupID
    where x.TransferStatus== null || (x.TransferStatus!= "01" && x.TransferStatus!= "02")
    select new 
    {
        //your properties
    }

).ToList();
```

Comment: It's not working, if I execute a SQL query I get 13 data, but if I debug the LINQ  that you provide only get 10 data. in SQL Query, they should filter one of the conditions (PaymentID or Total Payment).